# Which font is this? Used in Cyber Fiction films

Tags: fonts, font-identification

This font was used in the *Upgrade* movie [Police Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krm5S.png)

[image]

I have seen this type being used in many cyber fiction movies.

The font identification site I tried:-

[WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/%20%22WhatTheFont)

It gave many names. But I wonder if this is typeface is famous or something?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Font Squirrel Matcherator can match that font, although you will first have to edit the image to remove everything except text.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi, i realized I hadn't added the image itself. Lol

Comment: Well, that's a different one from the movie poster I was thinking about, but try editing it, rotate it until it's straight, and see if font squirrel can match it.

Comment: Font squirrel showing all kind of non matching fonts. WhatTheFont gave better suggestions.

Comment: I just tried it with font squirrel, and there is an almost perfect match.  As I said, you have to edit the image first to straighten it, unskew it a bit, brighten it up a bit.  Try harder.

Comment: The font is Orbitron Bold - a free font from fontzillion.

Comment: Gotcha. What you have to say about "Banque Gothique RR Medium"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "SF Chaerilidae - Regular".

I have matched the fonts here using this Link: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator?token=je4wglu1i151zj21

You can download the entire font family from here: https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/shyfoundry/sf-chaerilidae?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=sfchaerilidae

I have also attached the screenshots of the matched fonts so you can easily compare.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can I find a google font similar to this?